# HTML if statment with GWT UiBinder

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I am using an HTMLPanel in a UiBinder with GWT.  I want to reproduce the HTML

`<!--[if lt IE 10]>Email<![endif]-->`

so I can insert a label for an input field that uses a placeholder if the user is using an old browser.  Is this possible?  Is there a work around?

Comment: what do you mean by "I want to reproduce the HTML Email "..also can you provide some code to work/understand with

Comment: Sorry about that, the <!--[if lt IE 10]> parts weren't showing up becuase they were formatted out in the preview/view.  I fixed it so it is obvious what I am asking.